# How do I split a names column in a pandas data frame if only some of the names have middle names?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a pandas data frame of names and there are a few different formats of names. Some are 'first' 'last, others are 'first' 'middle' 'last', and others are 'first initial' 'second initial' 'last'. I would like to split these into three columns by using the strings. I am currently trying to use the split function but I am getting "ValueError: Columns must be same length as key" because some names will split into two columns and others will be split into three. How can I get around this?

```py
df = {'name': ['bradley efron', 'c arden pope', 'a l smith']}

mak_df[['First', 'Middle', 'Last']] = mak_df.Author_Name.str.split(" ", expand = True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround:

```
import pandas as pd
list_of_names = ['bradley efron', 'c arden pope', 'a l smith']

new_list =[]

for name in list_of_names:
    new_list.append(name.split(" "))

print(new_list)
for name in new_list:
    if (len(name)==2):
        name.insert(1," ")

print(new_list)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(new_list).T
df.index = ["first name","middle name","last name"]
df= df.T
print(df)
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way to go about this, but here's what I've got:

```
df = {'name': ['bradley efron', 'c arden pope', 'a l smith']}
df=pd.DataFrame(df)
df=df['name'].str.split(' ',expand=True)
df.columns=['first','middle','last']
df['last']=np.where(df['last'].isnull(),df['middle'],df['last'])
df['middle']=np.where((df['middle']==df['last']),'',df['middle'])
```